# Duplication of EndPoint but i cannot see it

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a web service.

This is (part of my) my web config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LicensedBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="NetTCPBehaviour">
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="0.00:00:30" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="License" behaviorConfiguration="LicensedBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="License.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NormalHttpBindingEndPoint" contract="ILicense" name="wsLicense" />
      </service>
      <service name="testme" behaviorConfiguration="NetTCPBehaviour">
        <endpoint  address="net.tcp://localhost:808/Sync2.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ISync2" name="wsMotionUploader" bindingConfiguration="NetTCPBindingEndPoint"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NormalHttpBindingEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="32768" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding  name="NetTCPBindingEndPoint" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" 
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="32768" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is my service:

```
public void DoWork(Stream image)
{
    var img = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(image);
}
```

This is my interface:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void DoWork(Stream image);
```

This is my client:

```
wsSyncFastest.Sync2Client client = new wsSyncFastest.Sync2Client();
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("d:\\bf.jpg"))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
         client.DoWork(ms);
         ms.Close();
    }
}
```

This is my error message:
An endpoint configuration section for contract 'wsSyncFastest.ISync2' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

this is my stack Error:

at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupChannel(ContextInformation configurationContext, String configurationName, ContractDescription contract, EndpointAddress address, Boolean wildcard, Boolean useChannelElementKind, ServiceEndpoint& serviceEndpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address, ContractDescription contract, ContextInformation configurationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address, ContractDescription contract)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
   at LiteEdition.wsSyncFastest.Sync2Client..ctor() in g:\dev20140604\LiteEdition\LiteEdition\Service References\wsSyncFastest\Reference.cs:line 51
   at LiteEdition.StartUp.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in g:\dev20140604\LiteEdition\LiteEdition\StartUp.cs:line 2646

I cannot see any probelms but obviously there is.

Can anyone assist?

ADDITIONAL:

My client app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsLicense" />
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISync2" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISync2" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://aurl/License.svc/License.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsLicense"
            contract="wsLicense.ILicense" name="wsLicense" />
        <endpoint address="http://www.informedmotion.co.uk/Sync2.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISync2"
            contract="wsSyncFastest.ISync2" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISync2" />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://dsvr019492/Sync2.svc" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISync2" contract="wsSyncFastest.ISync2"
            name="NetTcpBinding_ISync2">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/DSVR019492" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the name of the endpoint in when you create the proxy object and see if that fixes it.

If you intend on using the basicHttpBinding, it will be:

```
wsSyncFastest.Sync2Client client = new wsSyncFastest.Sync2Client("BasicHttpBinding_ISync2");
```

If you intend on using the netTcpBinding it will be:

```
wsSyncFastest.Sync2Client client = new wsSyncFastest.Sync2Client("NetTcpBinding_ISync2");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting.  I am not sure where i would do that. I have added to my original question with the client endpoint configuration.  Could show me by example please?  Thanks

Comment: I edited the answer to include the example. The endpoint names are in your client application configuration. Since you have two endpoints that service the same contract, the client proxy object will not know which one to use unless you specify it in the constructor when you build one.

Comment: The endpoint address for the client is incorrect. It should have one "License.svc"

Comment: Hi, I will test this as soon as I get back home :)  Thanks

Comment: Let me rephrase, the first endpoint address entry in the client app.config that has two License.svc in the value of the "address" is incorrect. The other two look alright.

Comment: Hi, i seem to be having other errors now. I have posted it as a new question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033483/how-dynaically-call-a-net-tcp-web-service  Thanks