# How to dynamically call a net.tcp Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to call a WCF from my C# desktop app but i get an error. This is my code:

```
//Client Code
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress addressSync = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("net.tcp://an ip address/Sync2.svc");
Shared.FactorySync = new System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<LiteEdition.wsSyncFastest.ISync2Channel>("NetTcpBinding_ISync2", addressSync);
Shared.UpLoadSync = Shared.FactorySync.CreateChannel();
```

**[QUESTION. If I dynamically create a client call to a WCF can I assume i do NOT need to include anything in th app.config file about the bindings?]**

```
//error message on this line:
Shared.UpLoadSync.UploadMotionDynamic2(new byte[1]{0}, 0, 0);

//IS:
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9349963'
```

.

```
//My Service:
public void UploadMotionDynamic2(byte[] jpegData, int status, int framePart)
{
    DAL dal = new DAL();
    try
    {
        if (jpegData != null)
    {
            LiveView2.SetNewFrame(status, framePart, jpegData);            
    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        email.SendError("Sync.UploadMotionDynamic:" + ex.ToString(), "");
    }
}

//In my Web.Config
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NetTCPBehaviour">
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="0.00:00:30" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="testme" behaviorConfiguration="NetTCPBehaviour">
        <endpoint  address="Sync2.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ISync" name="wsMotionUploader" bindingConfiguration="NetTCPBindingEndPoint">
          <!--<security mode="None"></security>-->
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding  name="NetTCPBindingEndPoint" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" 
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="32768" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Amended Code:

```
            System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding();
            System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http:ip/Sync2");

            System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel> factory =
                new System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel>(binding, address);

            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            channel.Open();
```

UPDATED TO THIS:

```
            System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding();                
            System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("net.tcp://ip/Sync2");
            System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<WindowsFormsApplication2.ws.ISync2Channel> factory =
                new System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<WindowsFormsApplication2.ws.ISync2Channel>(binding, address);
            factory.Endpoint.Contract.SessionMode = System.ServiceModel.SessionMode.Allowed;
            WindowsFormsApplication2.ws.ISync2Channel channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            channel.Open();
```

But get this error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

on the .Open() method.

Also, the 'WindowsFormsApplication2.ws.ISync2Channel' is defined because I had already added a reference to the Service.  If I had not what would I have
used instead?

///******************new settings:

```
Client code:

ws.Sync2Client wcf = new ws.Sync2Client("NetTcpBinding_ISync2");
wcf.UploadMotionDynamic2(new byte[1]{1},0,0);

Client App.Config:
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISync2" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISync2" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://ip/Sync2.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISync2"
                contract="ws.ISync2" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISync2" />
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://ip/Sync2.svc" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISync2" contract="ws.ISync2"
                name="NetTcpBinding_ISync2">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/ip" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Server Web.Config

-->

The error I get is on this line:

```
wcf.UploadMotionDynamic2(new byte[1]{1},0,0);
```

The error is:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
the stack is:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WindowsFormsApplication2.ws.ISync2.UploadMotionDynamic2(Byte[] jpegData, Int32 status, Int32 framePart)
   at WindowsFormsApplication2.ws.Sync2Client.UploadMotionDynamic2(Byte[] jpegData, Int32 status, Int32 framePart) in m:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Service References\ws\Reference.cs:line 81
   at WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in m:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.cs:line 581

This all works when I use http binding though...

The port 780 is open on my server.
the Net.Tcp.Listener Adaptor is running
Enabled Protocols in IIS has net.tcp

Still no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your using the wrong constructor for your requirements.
When using the [ChannelFactory(String, EndpointAddress)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574910(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor, the first parameter stands for the name of your endpoint configuration (in your config file).

Using the [ChannelFactory(Binding, EndpointAddress)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574914(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor will fulfill your requirement of passing the configuration programmatically.

> Use this constructor when you want to pass the binding and address information programmatically rather than using an application configuration file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me. I have updated my question with your suggestion but I still get an error...

Comment: The exception you are receiving is throwed by the Open() method, which you defined yourself in the ISync2Channel interface, and has nothing to do with your ChannelFactory.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for trying to help me.  At the end of the day i still cannot dynamically open/create a client proxy to my web service.

Comment: if i invoke this service directly on my server it works so it is all to do with my client code which is what I am trying to solve here :)

Comment: Instead of calling the Open() method (what does it even do?), what happens when you try to fire the UploadMotionDynamic2() method?

Comment: Hi, in a desperate attempt to problem solve this :) I have tried to connect to it normally:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ChannelFactory class to call the wcf service, in this case you dont need to have endpoints and bindings in configuration file. Everything(endpoints, behaviors) you can create in the c# something like below code

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://myurl:8080/ServiceFirst");
IService client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

check out this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: HI,  thanks for you comment. I am working with net.tcp. But thanks